# Simplest ways to cause stack overflow in C#, C++ and Java

Tags: c#, java, javascript, c++

I'm watching a C# tutorial and came across StackOverflowException.

the narrator gave a neat example of such an exception using the code snippet below,

```
public class Employee
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
       get{ return Name; }
    }
}
```

I'm looking for some example of this type of simple code in C++ and Java and more specially in javascript that can cause Stack Overflow.

Comment: Recursion: See Recursion.

Comment: Just write a recursive function without breakout condition in any language, it will give SO exception.

Comment: @GuruKara except for languages with tail recursion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        main(args);
    }
}
```

In general, any recursive function that does not terminate or have too many iterations will cause this problem.

Answer (score 13):

**This Explanation is the basic reason behind a StackOverflowException for Java, C, and C++.**

A stack overflow exception is generally caused in any language due to recursive method calls.

Suppose you have an method which is calling itself or any other method for an infinite, recursive loop; it will cause a Stackoverflowexception. The reason behind this is the method call stack gets filled, and it won't be able to accommodate any other method call.

**Method call stack looks like this picture.**

[image]

**Explanation** --  Suppose the Main method has five statements, and the third method has an call to methodA, then the execution of Main method gets paused at statement3 and methodA will be loaded into the call stack. Then method A has a call to methodB. So methodB also gets loaded into the stack.

So in this way infinite, recursive calls make the call stack get filled at which point it can't afford any more methods. So it throws a StackOverflowException.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. Note that languages that optimize [tail recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail-recursive) may not throw SO on function in the question.

Answer (score 2):

For your code snippet, this is due to recursion method call:

```
public string Name
{
   get{ return Name; }
}
```

You are calling the `Name` method/property recursively. The stack fills up (with the parent `Name` method) until it overflows and a `StackOverflowException` is thrown.

Answer (score 2):

```
public string Name
{
   get{ return Name; }
}
```

This property calling itself using with `return Name;`. That causes infinite recursion. That's why when you use this property, you get *[StackOverflowException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stackoverflowexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)*. I believe the right usage of this property should be:

```
public string Name
{
   get{ return _name; }
}
```

> StackOverflowException is thrown for execution stack overflow errors,
>   typically in case of a **very deep or unbounded recursion**.
>
> Starting with the .NET Framework version 2.0, a StackOverflowException
>   object cannot be caught by a try-catch block and the corresponding
>   process is terminated by default. Consequently, users are advised to
>   write their code to detect and prevent a stack overflow. For example,
>   **if your application depends on recursion, use a counter or a state
>   condition to terminate the recursive loop**.

Comment: This answer would benefit from an explanation of why `_name` should work where `Name` doesn't.